# Embed Google Spreadsheet on SquareSpace & make it responsive for Mobile

Tags: html, iframe, google-sheets, embed, squarespace

I'm trying to embed a google spreadsheet on my Square Space website. Unfortunately, the spreadsheet I get has horizontal and vertical scroll-bars whenever I switch to mobile view

```
<div class="sqs-block-content">
<iframe width="100%" height="800" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxfLMwwEWjyV-Avp9cWupPnJiwVq3GX6VcVRYuw-XQ0/pubhtml?single=false&widget=false&headers=false" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
</div>
```

How to make the spreadsheet responsive so that it fits on the iframe (thus, there will be no scroll bars as all the columns are visible)?

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to manipulate the inner html(html body of iframe) using jquery? I believe there should be a way or some way to achieve what I want.
I tried with some jquery libraries as well still no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reduce the size *and* content of the `<iframe>`, try the following:

- remove `width="100%" height="800"` from your `<iframe>`

then, **add** the following to your CSS:

```
iframe {
    width: 396vw;
    height: 3200px;
    border: 0;
    transform: scale(0.25);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, the spreadsheet fits on mobile devices now. But, It also scales down on desktop so the sheet is appearing smaller in desktop as well.

Comment: You only need to put the styles above in your `@media query` for mobile devices. If you don't have one, I'd be tempted to use something like: `@media only screen and (max-width: 790px) { ... }` or similar.